# How do I setup a folder with a different rule and another folder with a different rule

Tags: angularjs, eslint

My folder structure is as follows:

```
-client // Contains the front end and AngularJS code  
-server // Contains backend code  
-models // Contains backend code
```

Now, I wish to use [eslint angular](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular) only for the client folder whereas I wish to use [airbnb base](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base) for the other folders that are not inside the client folder.

I have two `.eslintrc.json` files - one in the client folder and one in the ROOT folder.

Client folder configuration looks like:

```
{
    "extends": "angular"
}
```

whereas the one in the root folder looks like:

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
    "root": true
}
```

Now, in the root folder, when I run `eslint .`, while the backend folders are being linted correctly, the front end doesn't seem to be using the angularjs eslint at all - I am getting errors about ES6 which I am not using the client folder. I don't also get errors about not following John Papa's style guide in the client folder (which the angular plugin should).

However, if I go inside the client folder and run the esling command inside it, it seems to use the correct configuration.

How do I configure it so that only client folder uses the angular eslint whereas the other folders use the airbnb one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Configuration for client and server code**

If you wonder how to lint different part of code, this is a suggestion.

```
- myproject
--- .eslintrc
--- src
------ client
--------- .eslintrc 
------ server
--------- .eslintrc
```

myproject/.eslintrc contains the common rules. For instance,

```
rules:
    brace-style: [2, "1tbs"]
    comma-style: [2, "last"]
    default-case: 2
    func-style: [2, "declaration"] ...
```

src/client/.eslintrc contains client side rules. For instance,

```
env:
    browser: true

globals:
    angular: false

plugins:
  - angular
```

src/server/.eslintrc contains server side rules. For instance

```
env:
    node: true
```

Usually I lint a javascript file when I save it.

ESLint is installed also globally. As stated in config help page of ESLint, a globally-installed instance of ESLint can only use globally-installed ESLint plugins. 
A locally-installed ESLint can make sure of both locally- and globally- installed ESLint plugins. That's I need to install also globally the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use two configs and two tasks:

`eslint -c .eslintrc-client.json client`

`eslint -c .eslintrc-server.json server models`